# Accessing hdf5 file datablock using tables rather than h5py

Tags: hdf5, h5py, pytables

I had had some success reading hdf5 files generated from MSC/Nastran using both h5py and tables. Now I’m trying to do the same with a file generated by Simcenter/Nastran and I’m having trouble because the data block includes a colon in the names.

This Syntax works using h5py:

```
hf=h5py.File(‘solidbeam-3prtfem-sol101.hdf','r')
myElm=hf['model']['geom2:elem_data']['geom2_chexa']
```

Typically I would try the following for tables:

```
hft=tables.open_file(‘solidbeam-3prtfem-sol101.hdf','r')
myElmTable=hft/model/geom2:elem_data/geom2_chexa
```

The `:` character in `geom2:elem` does not work.

The following syntax does work and prints item names as follows:

```
for obj in hft:
   print obj

/model/geom2:elem_data/geom2_chexa (Table(40,))
```

Do you have any advice on how this data-block should be referenced in tables?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The h5py version works because it's ok to have special characters in dict key string.  But names used like variable names or attributes can't have them.  I'm more familiar with h5py than tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @hpaulj noted, variable names can't include special characters (like `-`, `:`, `+`, etc). Your PyTables (aka tables) method to access objects is called "natural naming". PyTables has a `.get_node()` method to get around this limitation and will work with these object names. Note: when an object name has special characters, PyTables will issue a warning that you can't access that object with "natural naming" (as you already discovered). It's just a warning.

Modified code for PyTables from above:

```
hft = tables.open_file('solidbeam-3prtfem-sol101.hdf','r')
myElmTable = hft.get_node('/model/geom2:elem_data/geom2_chexa')
```

As an aside, I suggest using Python's context manager to open files. That way the file is closed automatically when you exit that code block. Example:

```
import tables as tb
with tb.open_file('solidbeam-3prtfem-sol101.hdf','r') as hft:
    myElmTable = hft.get_node('/model/geom2:elem_data/geom2_chexa')
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem.  I am trying to provide feedback to the developers of the application generating the h5 to change their naming to support natural naming but so far too little avail.

Comment: Glad that helped. Please mark as accepted if it answered your question.  The `get_node()` method is the way to go.  I stopped using the natural naming procedure after I discovered `get_node()`. You can use it when you are looping over datasets and it makes it easier converting code between pytables ahd h5py. Good luck!